# Entity Framework Core: generated query selects a column which does not exists anymore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity model generated by `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`.

It generated (among others) a class for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ProductId INT NOT NULL,
    CountryId NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);
```

Class:

```
public class MyTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
// extraction ...
public virtual DbSet<MyTable> MyTables { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("MyTable");
        entity.Property(e => e.CountryId).HasMaxLength(3);
    }
}
// ...
```

After some time I made a change to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ProductId INT NOT NULL,
    TheCountryId INT NOT NULL -- Rename and change the Data type
);
```

And of course to the class and `DbContext` as well.

Class:

```
public class MyTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int TheCountryId { get; set; }  // Rename and change the Data type
}
```

DbContext:

```
// extraction ...
public virtual DbSet<MyTable> MyTables { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("MyTable");
        // Remove restriction
    }
}
// ...
```

When I run `_db.MyTables.ToArray()` or similar code, Entity Framework generates queries which still select `CountryId` (and not `TheCountryId`)

```
SELECT 
    [m.MyTable].[Id], [m.MyTable].[ProductId], [m.MyTable].[CountryId], [m.MyTable].[TheCountryId]
FROM
    [MyTable] AS [m.MyTable]
```

Why does this happen? I removed all that indicates that the class had a property `CountryId`. I also deleted the bin an obj folders to make sure the program is a clear compilation. Nothing works. Is Entity Framework Core caching queries or is SQL Server doing this?

Comment: Are you configuring a relation between this table and the Countries table somewhere else?

Comment: After changing the structure of the database, you don't have to manually change the entities. You can run the command (`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`) for scaffolding again. Can you do that, let us know if you still seeing the issue please.